# Java InfluxDB: Map tags as well as fields in POJO from query

Tags: java, influxdb

Using the influxdb library in Java I'm trying to map the results of a query formed using the `QueryReactiveAPI` query builder to a POJO so I can store them for processing. I get that you need to use the `@Measurement` annotation on the class definition and the `@Column` annotation on class variables to map fields but is there the equivalent for tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `@Column` annotation for tags, simply include `tag = true` in the annotation, for example:

```
@Column(tag = true)
    String location;
```

Source: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java#writes-and-queries-in-influxdb-2x